# how can we autoscroll and autoloop flatlist in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I want my Flatlist autoscroll and loop in horizontal direction, please help me out
Thanks in Advance

```
          <FlatList
             style={{marginEnd:5}}
             timer={2000}
             //  width={deviceWidth}
              loop={true}
             // keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor.bind(this)}
              horizontal={true}
              onScrollToIndexFailed={info => {
                 const wait = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
                 wait.then(() => {
                    flatListFeaturedMobiles.current?.scrollToIndex({ index: info.index, animated: true });
                 });
               }}
             //  onScrollToIndexFailed={()=>{}}
              flatListRef={React.createRef()}
              ref={this.flatListFeaturedMobiles}
              autoscroll={true}
              
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        data={this.state.featuredMobiles}
        horizontal
```

Comment: Please ask a more specific question that "here is my code please make it do X or Y". What does the code you have do? What have you tried? What kind of thing are you building with it, to give answerers some context.

Comment: i have tried solution below, but it's giving error "scroll to index out of range"
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44475202/how-do-i-make-a-list-flatlist-automatically-scroll-through-the-elements-using

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll the list using Animated like check it [How do I make a list (FlatList) automatically scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44475202/how-do-i-make-a-list-flatlist-automatically-scroll-through-the-elements-using)

You can also use [react-native-autoscroll-flatlist#readme](https://github.com/RageBill/react-native-autoscroll-flatlist#readme)

For more detail you can read here [wants-to-autoscroll-flatlist-in-react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54569618/wants-to-autoscroll-flatlist-in-react-native)

Comment: i tried these solutions but, error occured "scroll to index out of range"

Comment: Checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43856264/flatlist-component-life-cycle-methods-scrolltoindex-scrolltoend-etc